# Django - ListView url not connecting to desired view

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I am new to Django and have hit a wall with a certain part of my project and I hope someone can help.

I have two ListViews in my views.py file which I would like to work similar to published/draft posts (I'm actually using sanitised and unsanitised reports). Currently, every time I try to access the "Unsanitised" list view (unsanitised_list.html), it just directs me to the the sanitised list view (intelreport_list.html)

views.py:

```
class IntelReportListView(ListView):
  model = IntelReport
  context_object_name = 'all_logs'

  def get_queryset(self):
    return IntelReport.objects.filter(create_date__lte=timezone.now()).order_by('-create_date')



class UnsanitisedListView(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):
    login_url = '/login/'
    redirect_field_name = 'intel_db/unsanitised_list.html'
    
    model = IntelReport

    def get_queryset(self):
      return IntelReport.objects.filter(sanitised__isnull=True).order_by('-create_date')
```

models.py

```
class IntelReport(models.Model):
    gpms_choices = (
      ***REDACTED***
    )
    gpms = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True, choices=gpms_choices)
    
    officer = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    create_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    sanitised = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    source_eval_choices = (
      ***REDACTED****
    )
    source_eval = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True, choices=source_eval_choices)
    
    intel_eval_choices = (
      ***REDACTED***
    )
    intel_eval = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True, choices=intel_eval_choices)

    report = models.TextField(max_length=5000, blank=True, null=True)

    def sanitised_log(self):
      self.sanitised = True
      self.save()

    def get_absolute_url(self):
      return reverse('log_details', kwargs={'pk':self.pk})

    def __str__(self):
      return str(self.pk)
```

urls.py

from django.urls import path
from intel_db import views

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('welcome/', views.AboutView.as_view(), name='about'),
    path('logs/', views.IntelReportListView.as_view(), name='log_list'),
    path('logs/<int:pk>/', views.IntelReportDetailView.as_view(), name='log_detail'),
    path('logs/new_log/', views.IntelReportCreateView.as_view(), name='new_log'),
    path('unsanitised/', views.UnsanitisedListView.as_view(), name='unsanitised'),
    path('logs/<int:pk>/sanitise_log/', views.sanitsed_report, name='sanitised_report'),
]
```

and on my landing page (landing.html), this is the link I'm using to try and reach the unsanitised_list.html:

```
      **<a href="{% url 'unsanitised' %}">**
```

I cannot figure out why it keeps redirecting me to intelreport_lists.html (the sanitised logs) rather than unsanitised_list.html (the unsanitised logs).

I hope I'm not just missing something really simple but I've been over it and tried to re-write it innumerable times and can't get it right.

I hope this is enough information and any help would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to override `template_name` when you extend `ListView`. I mean update your `IntelReportListView` and `UnsanitisedListView`like this,

```
class IntelReportListView(ListView):
  model = IntelReport
  context_object_name = 'all_logs'
  template_name = 'YOUR_APP_NAME/intelreport_list.html'

  def get_queryset(self):
    return IntelReport.objects.filter(create_date__lte=timezone.now()).order_by('-create_date')



class UnsanitisedListView(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):
    login_url = '/login/'
    redirect_field_name = 'intel_db/unsanitised_list.html'
    template_name = 'YOUR_APP_NAME/unsanitised_list.html'
    model = IntelReport

    def get_queryset(self):
      return IntelReport.objects.filter(sanitised__isnull=True).order_by('-create_date')
```

If you are interested to find out why it was redirecting to `intelreport_list.html` rather than `unsanitised_list.html`, whenever you extend `ListView` it will look for `MODEL_NAME_list.html` by default, where `MODEL_NAME` is name of the model that you have used inside your list views (in lower case). Since you have used `model = IntelReport` inside `UnsanitisedListView`, it's redirecting to `intelreport_lists.html`

Comment: Let me know if this is not helping

Comment: Ah that makes perfect sense! And everything is now working as I expected. Thank you for taking the time to answer and explain.